# Is ResponseStatus needed in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, error-handling, servicestack

Is ResponseStatus needed?

The wiki says that we need to have a ResponseStatus property in our response DTO to handle exception serialization:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation

However it looks like ResponseStatus is generated automatically even if there is no ResponseStatus property in the response DTO.

Do we need the ResponseStatus property?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Error Handling Docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling) explains how you can control which Services return a populated `ResponseStatus` DTO, i.e:

#### Error Response Types

The Error Response that gets returned when an Exception is thrown varies on whether a conventionally-named `{RequestDto}Response` DTO exists or not.

If it exists:

The `{RequestDto}Response` is returned, regardless of the service method's response type. If the `{RequestDto}Response` DTO has a **ResponseStatus** property, it is populated otherwise no **ResponseStatus** will be returned.  (If you have decorated the `{ResponseDto}Response` class and properties with `[DataContract]/[DataMember]` attributes, then **ResponseStatus** also needs to be decorated, to get populated).

Otherwise, if it doesn't:

A generic `ErrorResponse` gets returned with a populated **ResponseStatus** property.

The [Service Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net//clients-overview) transparently handles the different Error Response types, and for schema-less formats like JSON/JSV/etc there's no actual visible difference between returning a **ResponseStatus** in a custom or generic `ErrorResponse` - as they both output the same response on the wire.

### Custom Exceptions

Ultimately all ServiceStack WebServiceExceptions are just Response DTO's with a populated [ResponseStatus](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ResponseStatus.cs) that are returned with a HTTP Error Status. There are a number of different ways to customize how Exceptions are returned including:

#### Enabling StackTraces

By default displaying StackTraces in Response DTOs are only enabled in Debug builds, although this behavior is overridable with:

`csharp
SetConfig(new HostConfig { DebugMode = true });`

Comment: ResponseStatus still appears to be useful for C# clients, because if you return a success message, such as from a RequestFilter, you can read it if your DTO has ResponseStatus defined. I don't know of another way to do this using JsonServiceClient (though it would be nice).

Comment: I've also noticed if you don't include the ResponseStatus you don't get the default exception behaviour of a HTTP 400 when an ArgumentException is thrown.