# Error handling in ServiceStack new API

Tags: exception, error-handling, servicestack

I have simple service stack web service that takes Name as input parameter. From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750799/is-responsestatus-needed-in-servicestack), I understand ResponseStatus property is no longer required when using new API. But when I tried to compose a request with no Name using fiddler, it returns 400 response code as expected but didn't contain any information regarding the exception. So, does new API  provide error description out-of-box especially for non .NET clients. If it doesn't, is there possible way to provide this information.

```
public object Any(CustomerRequest request)
{
   if (request.Name == null)
   {
     throw new ArgumentException("Name is required");
   }

   var objCustomer = //get customer from DB

   return objCustomer;
}

public class CustomerRequest
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public bool IsActive {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: What is your service class inheriting from?

Comment: class CustomerService : Service

Comment: I wrote a quick test project based on the information in the question. I receive an 400 http code and an Error response in the body. A 500 error is for internal server errors so I think there could be a bug in your test project.

Comment: I'm sorry, it returns 400 code. And I am testing the service using fiddler customer?format=json, does the response include error status as property.

Comment: Using the fiddler composer or Firefox I get the JSON object: `{"ResponseStatus":{"ErrorCode":"ArgumentException","Message":"Name is required","Errors":[]}}`. For brevity I disabled the stacktrace.

Comment: Also here is a link to the test code http://pastebin.com/vqZSRs2n

Comment: When I debug, ArgumentException is thrown but the json is blank. Url is http://localhost:82/api/customer?format=json and GET operation. As mentioned in the OP, response object doesn't have ResponseStatus property. All I receive is blank with status code 400.

Comment: But when I add ResponseStatus property to response object, it is getting populated. So, do I need it per new API?

Comment: Can you upload your test project to dropbox or similar. I'll have a look at it and try to see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks very much for your followups. As the answer suggested, issue was with response name. It was CustomerResponse, so I had renamed it and it worked just fine.

Comment: But I've problem with naming convention now, I've followed same as ServiceStack tests code. Now I am wondering how to name service, request and response. It is not like Todo's example, where they pass in Todo and receive Todo. My application has only GET operations, so request will have no relation with response. Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I've CustomerService, CustomerRequest, Customer (response), do you guys foresee any problems with these names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add ResponseStaus with the new API. As per penfold's example, you should get `{"ResponseStatus":{"ErrorCode":"ArgumentException","Message":"Name is required","Errors":[]}}` as a response.

Do you still have a CustomerResponse class in your codebase? If so, try commenting it out or removing it. Even though you are returning `object` when an Exception occurs ServiceStack will still look for the conventionally-named Response type (see [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/WebRequestUtils.cs#L77)) and try to fill the ResponseStatus property.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Now, I am left with naming convention problem  posted in the comments above, can anyone please advise.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the 'naming convention problem'? If you return 'object' for your Service(s) the CustomerResponse class (and other 'Response' classes) is dead code so remove it. Do you have a need for the CustomReponse that I'm missing? If so maybe post another question.

Comment: Yes, I am just sending customer as response so that solves the problem. But if I'd to send custom response, then it should also be the same right, I mean populate the customer into the custom object and return it. Since return type is object.

Comment: I wish the [wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling) included this!