# ServiceStack metadata page throws MemberAccessException: Cannot create an abstract class

Tags: c#, servicestack

Let's say you have a request class AllCustomers that returns an IEnumerable

```
[Route("/customers")]
public class AllCustomers : IReturn<IEnumerable<Customer>>
{
}
```

If you go to the metadata page for that request you will get the following crash:

```
[MemberAccessException: Cannot create an abstract class.]
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.nativeGetUninitializedObject(RuntimeType type) +0
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(Type type) +56
ServiceStack.Text.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetConstructorMethodToCache>b__1() +38
ServiceStack.Text.ReflectionExtensions.CreateInstance(Type type) +64
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Metadata.JsonMetadataHandler.CreateMessage(Type dtoType) +49
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Metadata.BaseMetadataHandler.CreateResponse(Type type) +267
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Metadata.BaseMetadataHandler.ProcessOperations(HtmlTextWriter writer, IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes) +688
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Metadata.BaseMetadataHandler.Execute(HttpContext context) +267
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.HttpHandlerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +84
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

I think the implementation of the metadata page should not crash when the response for a given request is an IEnumerable because this is a perfectly valid way to implement interfaces to your services (and its more preferable than returning a List). It should be smart enough to instantiate a List for the samples section if it sees IEnumerable as the return type. At least it shouldn't crash if the return type isn't instantiable...

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with `IEnumerable`? If you change `IEnumerable` to `IList` or just `List` in your `IReturn` declaration, do you get the same exception? How is the `Customer` class declared?

Comment: Interfaces are most definitely [not a perfect valid way to define service interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785).

Comment: Well according to lots of folks, [returning List<T> in public APIs is not a good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387937/why-is-it-considered-bad-to-expose-listt). I agree with [Krzysztof Cwalina's recommendation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/26/474010.aspx)

Comment: Are you just going to take blanket advice out of a context and apply it to every situation? This is exactly how cargo cult mentality spreads. This has nothing to do with a defining a service API boundary or ServiceStack. I've already provided a link to actual implementation issues for using interfaces across process boundaries and how it violates the core tenants of a service - feel free to ignore it and follow alternative advice on the Internet you think is more relevant and specific to your use-case.

Comment: The implementation issue you talk about in your link doesn't apply here: when you specify IEnumerable<Customer> as the return type, no type information needs to be passed in Json. It would be bloating the Json if the DTO used IReturn<IEnumerable<object>> or IReturn<List<object>>.My problem with using Lists in public APIs is that it gives a false representation of the API: it suggests a client could Add or Remove from the result of a service call which would obviously only do so for the local collection. Just trying a to have a constructive discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack wants you to encapsulate your responses inside its own class. So you would create a AllCustomerResponse class with a Customers IEnumerable property.

Comment: That [used to be the case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11750800/85785), now the [New API supports clean responses](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api). The problem is with using interfaces to define the service layer.

Comment: I have been using the new API but did not notice this change. Thanks!