# ServiceStack exception serialization behaviour

Tags: serialization, error-handling, servicestack, servicestack-text

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to ServiceStack

Given the following Service:

```
public class TestService : Service
{
    public TestResponse Get(Test request)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Message))
            throw new ArgumentException("Message is required");

        return new TestResponse();
    }
}
```

and the following request/response DTO's :

```
[Route("/test", "GET")]
public class Test : IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class TestResponse
{
    public IList<Test> TestList { get; set; }
}
```

I would expect the following response when I try to access **/test** :

```
{
    "responseStatus": {
        "errorCode": "ArgumentException",
        "message": "Message is required",
        "errors": []
    }
}
```

Instead I get an empty JSON response. It is however returning the correct status code (400 Bad Request).

I thought it would be quite common to name your DTO's in this manner in ServiceStack with Something and then SomethingResponse. To get it to return the exception as a serialized ResponseStatus object I have discovered that I can either rename my request DTO from Test to TestRequest and/or include a ResponseStatus property in my response DTO.

Is this expected behaviour?

**Update**

I should include that the issue only occurs if the name of my response DTO ends with Response (case sensitive). If my request/response DTO's are called Foo and Bar respectively, I receive a properly formatted JSON response with the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, [don't use interfaces on DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785) and for the docs on [ServiceStack Error Responses](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#error-response-types) it says:

---

#### Error Response Types

The Error Response that gets returned when an Exception is thrown varies on whether a conventionally-named `{RequestDto}Response` DTO exists or not.

If it exists:

The `{RequestDto}Response` is returned, regardless of the service method's response type. If the `{RequestDto}Response` DTO has a **ResponseStatus** property, it is populated otherwise no **ResponseStatus** will be returned.

Otherwise, if it doesn't:

A generic `ErrorResponse` gets returned with a populated **ResponseStatus** property.

The [Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) transparently handles the different Error Response types, and for schema-less formats like JSON/JSV/etc there's no actual visible difference between returning a **ResponseStatus** in a custom or generic `ErrorResponse` - as they both output the same response on the wire.

---

Given the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) lets you [return clean responses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11750800/85785) whilst still retaining the Error information, your DTOs should be either:

```
[Route("/test", "GET")]
public class Test : IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class TestResponse
{
    public List<Test> TestList { get; set; }

    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can go without the Response DTO and return the clean list, e.g:

```
[Route("/test", "GET")]
public class Test : IReturn<List<Test>>
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class TestService : Service
{
    public List<Test> Get(Test request)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Message))
            throw new ArgumentException("Message is required");

        return new List<Test>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I din't quite get your comment regarding not using interfaces on DTO's. The only interface I have in my example is the IReturn<TestResponse> which I understand is reccomended in order to support static typing on the client side. Also I thought that by using the New API I didn't have to add the ResponseStatus property.

Comment: @ChristianHagelid I was referring to the `IList<Test> TestList` property.